# Data Marketplace - Enabling "Get Data" button

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My objective is to create a custom role, with least privileges that provides capability to "Get Data" in Data Marketplace. This is primarily intended from "consumer" perspective and NOT "provider" perspective

Here are the options I tried, but still "Get Data" button is disabled. What other privileges are required to enable "Get Data" button.

Option-1

- CREATE ROLE DX_CONSUMER_ROLE (executed using USERADMIN)
- GRANT IMPORT SHARE ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE DX_CONSUMER_ROLE (executed using
  ACCOUNTADMIN)

*Conclusion*: "Get Data" button is still disabled when using DX_CONSUMER_ROLE

Option-2

- CREATE ROLE CSTM_SYSADMIN_ROLE  (executed using USERADMIN)
- GRANT ROLE SYSADMIN TO ROLE CSTM_SYSADMIN_ROLE (executed using SECURITYADMIN)
- GRANT ROLE DX_CONSUMER_ROLE TO ROLE CSTM_SYSADMIN_ROLE (executed using SECURITYADMIN)

*Conclusion*: "Get Data" button is still disabled when using CSTM_SYSADMIN_ROLE

Per Snowflake documentation, it mentions IMPORT SHARE is good enough, but I am unsuccessful so far. What am I missing here. Any advise.

---

*Here is further observations after above original post ...*

1. Standard Lists (aka Free Data Sets), by default has "REQUEST" button (and disabled)
2. If IMPORT SHARE is provided through ROLE Hierarchy like Option-2 above, then "REQUEST" button changes to "GET DATA" button (but still disabled)
3. Only when IMPORT SHARE is provided directly to SYSADMIN, then "GET DATA" button is enabled.

Looks like custom role cannot be used to enable marketplace "GET DATA" button and it has to be IMPORT SHARE for SYSADMIN. From operationalization perspective within an organization, I personally prefer to segregate regular SYSADMIN (who can creates local DBs) vs MARKETPLACE Consumer SYSADMIN (who can only imports shares from marketplace). Appreciate if someone can suggest a workaround to accommodate this.

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would share my example that this worked for me in my testing for a bare minimum "get data" from the marketplace type of role:

```
create role marketplace_consumer_role;
grant IMPORT SHARE on account to role marketplace_consumer_role;
grant CREATE DATABASE on account to role marketplace_consumer_role;
```

Comment: Thanks @Suzy Lockwood for the response. Your response works when `marketplace_consumer_role` is used. Additionally, what I have observed is, if `marketplace_consumer_role` is granted to another role (let's say `parent_role`), then when `parent_role` is used the GET DATA button is disabled, but when switched to `marketplace_consumer_role' it is enabled. My understanding was parent_roles automatically inherit child roles, but looks like it is not in this case.

Comment: Interesting find!  Yes, seems like I have to switch to the child role to "get data". I am not sure if that is expected; let me report that to the data marketplace team.